# QBXML: How do I retrieve the bank account and routing values that are saved on the employee for direct deposit?

Tags: c#, quickbooks

I can't find anything documented that has it at the moment?  Anyone done this before?  Preferably in csharp but I'll take anything.

Answer (score 0):

QuickBooks does not expose this information via an API.